# How to prevent error alerts on Fine-Uploader?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Is there any way to prevent alerts where the `onError` callback is fired?

I only need to capture the error and display it in a different way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, simply override the [`showMessage` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/styling.html#dialogs).

For example:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'my/endpoint'
    },
    callbacks: {
        onError: function(fileId, filename, reason, maybeXhr) {
            //do something with the error
        }
    },
    showMessage: function(message) {
        //either include an empty body, or some other code to display (error) messages
    }
});
```

Comment: @mfeltner your edit seems to point to a non-existing link, while the original link seems to be correct.

Comment: @AlokSinghal Sorry about that.  The link will be live very shortly.

Comment: @AlokSinghal, The link has propagated.